# BroadcastReceiver permission for adb shell

Tags: android, permissions, broadcastreceiver, android-permissions

Consider a simple tool using a `BroadcastReceiver` to achieve a simple goal. Because this should not be used by other applications, it defines a permission with a protectionLevel of `signature` or `signatureOrSystem`:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="any.test">

    <permission
        android:name="any.test.PERMISSION"
        android:protectionLevel="signatureOrSystem" />

    <application android:label="AnyTest">
        <receiver
            android:name=".Receiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="any.test.PERMISSION" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Now I'd like to test this by sending broadcasts via

```
adb shell am broadcast -n any.test/.Receiver
```

from my computer. While this works perfectly fine on an emulator, it doesn't work at all on a real device when this permission is set. If the permission is not set, everything works as intended.

So how can I define or grant the permission so that I can test all this on a real device with `ADB`?

I want to make this exported receiver a little more secure in debug mode, so if there's a special permission for `ADB` usage or a run-time test to only allow calls from `ADB` I can implement in `Receiver.onReceive(Context, Intent)`, it would help too. The receiver doesn't have to work for `ADB` and other apps at the same time.

Comment: I don't understand this statement: "...doesn't work ... as long as the permission is set. Without it all works fine..." are you saying it works **without** the permission and you want it to not to work?

Comment: Here is my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35603856/how-to-send-broadcast-with-permission-from-command-line/55824554#55824554

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A root shell can send any broadcast protected by any permissions.
A normal shell also has been granted lots of permissions, check this file in the AOSP souce code: [frameworks\base\packages\Shell\AndroidManifest.xml](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/packages/Shell/AndroidManifest.xml).

Replace your `any.test.PERMISSION` with one permission in this file that the protectionLevel is `signatureOrSystem`, like `android.permission.REAL_GET_TASKS`. After that, you can send broadcast to this receiver in shell, but other 3rd app can not.

Comment: Replace your `any.test.PERMISSION` with one permission in this file that the protectionLevel is `signatureOrSystem`, like `android.permission.REAL_GET_TASKS`.  After that ,you can send broadcast to this receiver in shell, but other 3rd app can not.

Comment: The `Shell` package was introduced with Android 4.3 though.

Comment: @tynn: can you please provide the exact shell command which you used which resolved your problem?

Comment: @srv_sud there's no shell command involved in resolving my issue. Only using a different `android:permission` for the receiver.

Comment: @tynn: I posted a question [How to send broadcast with permission from command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35603856/how-to-send-broadcast-with-permission-from-command-line) . Some one suggested me to check with your answer regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

I did not want to change the permissions. Instead I created an Activity as a proxy: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70110207/1651697