# How to send broadcast with permission from command line

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, adb

I have a broadcast receiver in a app which uses my permission `com.myexample.permission.MY_PERMISSION`.

I am able to send the broadcast using

`sendBroadcast(intent, "com.myexample.permission.MY_PERMISSION")`

from activities.

To send a broadcast for action as `com.com.myexample.MY_ACTION` and extra data with key as `MY_EXTRA` below command can be used:

```
$adb shell am broadcast -a com.com.myexample.MY_ACTION
--ez MY_EXTRA true
```

But how to send broadcast with permission `com.myexample.permission.MY_PERMISSION` to the app from command line using adb shell commands??

Comment: Could you add the relevant portions of your manifest?

Answer (score 5):

Use arg `--receiver-permission` which belongs to subcmd `broadcast`:

```sh
adb shell am broadcast -a com.com.myexample.MY_ACTION --receiver-permission com.myexample.permission.MY_PERMISSION
```

Comment: I will plus 1 this when you put quotation marks around the name of the permission - then it works!

Answer (score 2):

If my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35194227/3928104) is not what you are looking for, try `pm grant PACKAGE PERMISSION`:

1. add `"development"` level when define 
   `com.myexample.permission.MY_PERMISSION` in your app, like `android:protectionLevel="signature|development"`
2. grant this permission to "shell" in adb shell:
   `pm grant com.android.shell com.myexample.permission.MY_PERMISSION`

Comment: I'd like to know how you do *1.*

Comment: And *2.* sadly yields `Operation not allowed: java.lang.SecurityException: Package com.android.shell has not requested com.myexample.permission.MY_PERMISSION`.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at [this post](https://plus.google.com/108612553581259107752/posts/ERVnjUAjsbZ) try removing the permission temporarily when you're doing testing from `adb`, and then re-adding the permission when you're ready to test it through a real broadcast.

If that is not acceptable, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35194227/2367225) may be of some help.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have already reffered to this post. But my requirement is to such that I need to have to use the permission. 
I would have done this with sample app. but for some test environment I need it to it through adb shell command scripts.

Comment: Take a look at the 2nd link in my edited response. I've never personally used it, but might be able to help you.

Comment: I am able to send broadcast using the the app. But my problem is that i need to send it using adb shell commands and permission I dont want to remove, this is my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a BroadcastingActivity that would receive the intent sent by adb and broadcasted it with the correct permissions. In this way the broadcast itself is consistent between debug/release and the BroadcastingActivity can be moved to the debug build type.